# How to advoid Maximum view state size limit (170KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 292.001KB

Tags: apex, attachment, exception, viewstate, try-catch

I currently have an apex class which creates an object record and attaches 2 files. I added a loop to be able to have the option to add more attachments based on counter. I currently have some required fields and some parameters passed trough the url. If one of the required fields do not get filled and the filesize is larger than viewstate are I get the error:

> Maximum view state size limit (170KB) exceeded. Actual view state size
>   for this page was 292.001KB

I have read several solutions to use transient or optimize soql but I dont think I can optimize more than i currently have. How do I solve this?

Apex class

```
public class test2 {
    private final Career__c webCareer;
    public static List<Attachment> attachments {get; set;}  
    public List<Attachment> newAttachments {get; set;}
    public static integer count {get;set;}
    public boolean hasAttachment {get; set;}
    public String webId {get; set;} 

    public static String  headerdata{get;set;}
    public static String paramFunction  = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('function');
    public static String paramCountry   = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('country');
    public static String paramArea      = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('area');
    public static String paramJob       = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('job');
    public static String JobPostingName {get; set;}

    public test2(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        webCareer = (Career__c)stdController.getRecord();
        id RTid = [SELECT CareerApplicant__c FROM RecordtypeId__c][0].CareerApplicant__c;
        if(RTId !=null){
            webCareer.RecordTypeId = RTId;
        }
        newAttachments=new List<Attachment>{new Attachment()};

        if(!String.isBlank(paramFunction)) webCareer.Function__c = restoreWhitespace(paramFunction);
        if(!String.isBlank(paramCountry)) webCareer.Country__c = restoreWhitespace(paramCountry);
        if(!String.isBlank(paramArea)) webCareer.Area__c = restoreWhitespace(paramArea);
        if(!String.isBlank(paramJob)){
            webCareer.Job_Posting__c = restoreWhitespace(paramJob);
            JobPostingName = [SELECT jobposition__c FROM Career__c WHERE Id = :paramJob][0].jobposition__c;
        }
        webCareer.Status__c = 'New';
        webCareer.Name = webCareer.First_Name__c + ' ' + webCareer.Last_Name__c;
    }
    public string restoreWhitespace(string input){
        if(input != null){
            return input.replaceAll('00000000', ' ');
        }
        return null;
    }
    public PageReference saveLead() {
        headerdata= ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
        Integer NumberOfAtt = 0;
        boolean hasAtt = false;
        if(newAttachments != null){
            for (Attachment newAtt : newAttachments) {
                if (newAtt.Body != null) NumberOfAtt = NumberOfAtt + 1;
            }
            if (NumberOfAtt == 2 || Test.isRunningTest())hasAtt = true;
        }
        //checks
        if(!hasAtt && NumberOfAtt != 2){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Upload 2 files'));
            count  = NumberOfAtt;     
            system.debug('https://' + headerdata + '/apex/webToCareerAttachment?area='+ paramArea + '&country=' + paramCountry + '&function=' +  paramFunction + '&job=' + paramJob);
            return null; 
        }else{
        try {
            webCareer.Name = webCareer.First_Name__c + ' ' + webCareer.Last_Name__c;
            insert(webCareer);
            webCareer.Name = webCareer.First_Name__c + ' ' + webCareer.Last_Name__c;
            save(webCareer.id); 
            webCareer.clear();  
        }
        catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
            return null;
        }
        PageReference p = new PageReference('https://www.google.com/');
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;
            }
    }
    public List<Attachment> getAttachments()
    {
        if (null==attachments) attachments=[select Id, ParentId, Name, Description from Attachment where parentId=:webCareer.id];
        return attachments;
    }
    public void addMore()
    {
        for (Integer idx=0; idx<1; idx++)
        {
            newAttachments.add(new Attachment());
        }
    }    
    public void save(id pId)
    {
        List<Attachment> toInsert=new List<Attachment>();
        list<ContentVersion> vList = new list<ContentVersion>();
        for (Attachment newAtt : newAttachments)
        {
            if (newAtt.Body!=null)
            {
                ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
                v.versionData = newAtt.body;
                v.title = newAtt.name;
                v.FirstPublishLocationId = pId;
                v.pathOnClient = newAtt.name;          
                v.Description = newAtt.name;
                vList.add(v);             
            }else{
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
            }
        }
        insert vList; 
        newAttachments.clear();
        attachments=null;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have it both ways (required fields and storing the files in the view state). Either drop the required fields bit (or make it a separate page/step), or switch to a pure client-side script with jQuery/Lightning/React/Angular/something-else. The view state is going to kill your performance, so any hiccup at all will crash the page due to this limit.

Comment: Does it has to be a separate page or wil a separate visualforce component also suffice?

Comment: @Thomas You can get away using components, or even just rendering parts of the page via `rendered` attributes. The point is, you need to make sure that no type of validation interrupts you from processing the files (e.g. saving them).